# Scala - Reduce list of tuples by key

Tags: scala

I have list of tuples which contains `userId` and `point`. I want to combine or reduce this list by the key.

```
val points: List[(Int, Double)] = List(
  (1, 1.0),
  (2, 3.2),
  (4, 2.0),
  (1, 4.0),
  (2, 6.8)
)
```

The expected result should look like:

```
List((1, 5.0), (2, 10.0), (4, 2.0))
```

I tried with `groupBy` and `mapValue`, but got an error:

```
val aggrPoint: Map[Int, Double] = incomes.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(seq => seq.reduce(_._2 + _._2))

Error:(16, 180) type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: (Int, Double)
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a idiomatic way to achieve this?

P.S) I found that in Spark `aggregateByKey` does this job. But, is there a built-in method in Scala?

Comment: Making this a `List` again is kind of resource-intensive. Most concise solutions will make this into a `Map` then convert it into a `List` - could you just keep it as a `Map[Int,Double]`?

Comment: Good point! Yes, nothing hurt to keep it as `Map[Int,Double]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > What am I doing wrong, and is there a idiomatic way to achieve this?

***let's go step by step to see what are you doing wrong***. (I am going to use **REPL**)

first of all lets *define the points*

```
scala> val points: List[(Int, Double)] = List(
     |   (1, 1.0),
     |   (2, 3.2),
     |   (4, 2.0),
     |   (1, 4.0),
     |   (2, 6.8)
     | )
points: List[(Int, Double)] = List((1,1.0), (2,3.2), (4,2.0), (1,4.0), (2,6.8))
```

As you can see that you have `List[Tuple2[Int, Double]]` so when you do `groupBy` and `mapValues` as

```
scala> points.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(seq => println(seq))
List((2,3.2), (2,6.8))
List((4,2.0))
List((1,1.0), (1,4.0))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Unit] = Map(2 -> (), 4 -> (), 1 -> ())
```

You can see that `seq` object is of `List[Tuple2[Int, Double]]` again *but only contains the grouped tuples as list*.

So when you apply `seq.reduce(_._2 + _._2)`, the `reduce` function takes two inputs of `Tuple2[Int, Double]` but the output is `Double` only which *doesn't match for the next iteration on `seq` as the expected input is `Tuple2[Int, Double`]*. **Thats the main issue**. All you have to do is *match the input and output types for `reduce` function*

One way would be to match `Tuple2[Int, Double]` as

```
scala> points.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(seq => seq.reduce{(x,y) => (x._1, x._2 + y._2)})
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,(Int, Double)] = Map(2 -> (2,10.0), 4 -> (4,2.0), 1 -> (1,5.0))
```

But this isn't your desired output, so *you can extract the double value from the reduced `Tuple2[Int, Double]`* as

```
scala> points.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(seq => seq.reduce{(x,y) => (x._1, x._2 + y._2)}._2)
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(2 -> 10.0, 4 -> 2.0, 1 -> 5.0)
```

or you can *just use `map` before you apply `reduce` function* as

```
scala> points.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(seq => seq.map(_._2).reduce(_ + _))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(2 -> 10.0, 4 -> 2.0, 1 -> 5.0)
```

I *hope the explanation is clear enough to understand your mistake* and you must have understood how a `reduce` function works

Answer (score 3):

You can `map` the tuples in the `mapValues` to their 2nd elements then `sum` them as follows:

```
points.groupBy(_._1).mapValues( _.map(_._2).sum ).toList
// res1: List[(Int, Double)] = List((2,10.0), (4,2.0), (1,5.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collect`

```
points.groupBy(_._1).collect{
   case e => e._1 -> e._2.map(_._2).sum
}.toList
//res1: List[(Int, Double)] = List((2,10.0), (4,2.0), (1,5.0))
```